# Mapping subfolder to subdomain - Google App Engine

Tags: java, subdomain

I hava a Java dynamic web.
I want to map a url like this: `domain.com/something/whatever` to `something.domain.com/whatever`

How can I do that?

Comment: what web framework do you use?

Comment: I use Struts 2. thank you!